# Why is my animation working in PyCharm, but not in Spyder?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, spyder

So I'm quite new to programming and I've been working on a program that describes motion of bowling ball (projectile motion, collisions with the ground, slipping and rolling). Anyways, my code seems to be working fine so far and I decided to make animation of ball movement using matplotlib's animate function. I'm working in Spyder and my animation doesn't start, but when I copy the code to PyCharm it works perfectly. I'm asking if someone can check it out and suggest what could be done to show animation in Spyder. Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym
import time

sym.init_printing()
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation



def fun_projectile_motion(t, y):
    """
    Function is used to solve differential equations,
    while the object is in the air.
    """
    return y[1], 0, y[3], - g


def fun_slipping_rolling(t, y):
    """
    Function is used to solve differential equations,
    while the object is slipping and rolling.
    """
    return y[1], -mi * g, y[3], (5 * mi * g) / (2 * radius)

def fun_slipping_rolling_backwards(t, y):
    """
    Function is used to solve differential equations,
    while the object is slipping and rolling in negative x direction.
    """
    return y[1], mi * g, y[3], (5 * -mi * g) / (2 * radius)


def fun_rolling(t, y):
    """
    Function is used to solve differential equations,
    while the object is rolling.
    """
    return y[1], -5 / 7 * g * theta


def fun_rolling_backwards(t, y):
    """
    Function is used to solve differential equations,
    while the object is rolling in negative x direction.
    """
    return y[1], 5 / 7 * g * theta


class Balls:
    def __init__(self,list,time_array):
        self.time_array=time_array
        self.list=[]
        for i in list:
            self.add_ball(i)
    def add_ball(self, ball):
        self.list.append(ball)

    def print(self):
        for i in self.list:
            i.print()

    def time_solution(self):
        """Function that computes motion parameters for each ball, at each time interval"""
        for i in range(len(self.time_array) - 1):
            for ball in self.list:
                if i==0:
                    current_values =[ball.get_distance_x(),ball.get_velocity_x(),ball.get_distance_y(),
                                  ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                ball.list.append(current_values)
            if ball.get_motion_status() == 'projectile_motion':

                y_0 = np.array(
                    [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(), ball.get_velocity_y()])
                solution = solve_ivp(fun_projectile_motion, (time_array[i], time_array[i + 1]), y_0)
                ball.set_distance_x(solution.y[0][-1])
                ball.set_velocity_x(solution.y[1][-1])
                ball.set_distance_y(solution.y[2][-1])
                ball.set_velocity_y(solution.y[3][-1])

                current_values = [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(),
                                  ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                ball.list.append(current_values)


            elif ball.get_motion_status() == 'collision':
                if abs(ball.get_velocity_y() * epsilon) >= 0.1:
                    ball.set_velocity_y(ball.get_velocity_y() * epsilon * (-1))
                    ball.set_distance_y(radius)
                    current_values = [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(),
                                      ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                    ball.list.append(current_values)

                elif abs(ball.get_velocity_y() * epsilon) < 0.1:
                    print(f'Time elapsed after last collision is{i * a / b: .2f} s.')
                    print(f'Distance x after last collision is{ball.get_distance_x(): .2f} m.')
                    ball.set_velocity_y(0)
                    ball.set_distance_y(radius)
                    current_values = [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(),ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                    ball.list.append(current_values)
                    ball.set_time_after_collision(time_array[i])

                else:
                    print('An Error has occured, regarding collision')
            elif ball.get_motion_status() == 'sliding':
                if i == 0:
                    ball.set_time_after_collision(0)
                if ball.get_velocity_x()>0:
                    if abs(ball.get_velocity_x()) - abs(ball.get_velocity_phi()) * ball.get_radius() < 0.1:
                        print(f'Time elapsed after sliding is{i * a / b: .2f} s.')
                        print(f'Distance x after sliding is{ball.get_distance_x(): .2f} m.')
                        print(f'v_x: {ball.get_velocity_x()} m/s.')
                        print(f'v_phi: {ball.get_velocity_phi()} rad/s.')
                        print(f'Distance phi after sliding: {ball.get_distance_phi()} rad.')
                        ball.set_velocity_phi(ball.get_velocity_x() / ball.get_radius())
                        current_values = [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(),ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                        ball.list.append(current_values)

                        """Used to animate ball movement:"""
                        ball.set_time_after_sliding(time_array[i])
                        ball.set_distance_phi_after_sliding(ball.get_distance_phi())
                        ball.set_velocity_x_after_sliding(ball.get_velocity_x())
                        ball.set_distance_x_after_sliding(ball.get_distance_x())



                    else:
                        y_0 = np.array([ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_phi(),ball.get_velocity_phi()])
                        solution = solve_ivp(fun_slipping_rolling, (time_array[i], time_array[i + 1]), y_0)
                        ball.set_distance_x(solution.y[0][-1])
                        ball.set_velocity_x(solution.y[1][-1])
                        ball.set_distance_phi(solution.y[2][-1])
                        ball.set_velocity_phi(solution.y[3][-1])

                        current_values = [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(),ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                        ball.list.append(current_values)
                else:
                    if abs(ball.get_velocity_x()) - abs(ball.get_velocity_phi()) * ball.get_radius() < 0.1:
                        print(f'Time elapsed after sliding is{i * a / b: .2f} s.')
                        print(f'Distance x after sliding is{ball.get_distance_x(): .2f} m.')
                        print(f'v_x: {ball.get_velocity_x()} m/s.')
                        print(f'v_phi: {ball.get_velocity_phi()} rad/s.')
                        print(f'Distance phi after sliding: {ball.get_distance_phi()} rad.')
                        ball.set_velocity_phi(ball.get_velocity_x() / ball.get_radius())
                        current_values = [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(),ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                        ball.list.append(current_values)

                        """Used to animate ball movement:"""
                        ball.set_time_after_sliding(time_array[i])
                        ball.set_distance_phi_after_sliding(ball.get_distance_phi())
                        ball.set_velocity_x_after_sliding(ball.get_velocity_x())
                        ball.set_distance_x_after_sliding(ball.get_distance_x())



                    else:
                        y_0 = np.array([ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_phi(),ball.get_velocity_phi()])
                        solution = solve_ivp(fun_slipping_rolling_backwards, (time_array[i], time_array[i + 1]), y_0)
                        ball.set_distance_x(solution.y[0][-1])
                        ball.set_velocity_x(solution.y[1][-1])
                        ball.set_distance_phi(solution.y[2][-1])
                        ball.set_velocity_phi(solution.y[3][-1])

                        current_values = [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(),ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                        ball.list.append(current_values)
                

            elif ball.get_motion_status() == 'rolling':
                if i == 0:
                    ball.set_time_after_sliding(0)
                    ball.set_velocity_x_after_sliding(ball.get_velocity_x())
                    ball.set_distance_x_after_sliding(ball.get_distance_x())
                    
                if ball.get_velocity_x()>0:
                    if abs(ball.get_velocity_x()) < 0.1:

                        ball.set_velocity_x(0)
                        ball.set_velocity_phi(0)
                        current_values = [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(),ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                        ball.list.append(current_values)
                        ball.set_distance_phi_after_rolling(ball.get_distance_phi())
                        ball.set_time_after_rolling(time_array[i])


                        print(f'Time elapsed after rolling is{i * a / b: .2f} s.')
                        print(f'Distance x after rolling is{ball.get_distance_x(): .2f} m.')
                        print(f'Distance_phi after rolling: {ball.get_distance_phi()} rad.')
                        print(f'----------------------------------------------------------------')


                    else:
                        y_0 = np.array([ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x()])
                        solution = solve_ivp(fun_rolling, (time_array[i], time_array[i + 1]), y_0)
                        ball.set_distance_x(solution.y[0][-1])
                        ball.set_velocity_x(solution.y[1][-1])
                        ball.set_velocity_phi(ball.get_velocity_x() / ball.get_radius())
                        ball.set_distance_phi(ball.get_distance_phi_after_sliding() + (ball.get_distance_x() - ball.get_distance_x_after_sliding()) / ball.get_radius())
                        current_values = [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(),
                                          ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                        ball.list.append(current_values)
                else:
                    if abs(ball.get_velocity_x()) < 0.1:

                        ball.set_velocity_x(0)
                        ball.set_velocity_phi(0)
                        current_values = [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(),
                                          ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                        ball.list.append(current_values)


                        ball.set_distance_phi_after_rolling(ball.get_distance_phi())
                        ball.set_time_after_rolling(time_array[i])


                        print(f'Time elapsed after rolling is{i * a / b: .2f} s.')
                        print(f'Distance x after rolling is{ball.get_distance_x(): .2f} m.')
                        print(f'Distance_phi after rolling: {ball.get_distance_phi()} rad.')
                        print(f'----------------------------------------------------------------')


                    else:
                        y_0 = np.array([ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x()])
                        solution = solve_ivp(fun_rolling_backwards, (time_array[i], time_array[i + 1]), y_0)
                        ball.set_distance_x(solution.y[0][-1])
                        ball.set_velocity_x(solution.y[1][-1])
                        ball.set_velocity_phi(ball.get_velocity_x() / ball.get_radius())
                        ball.set_distance_phi(ball.get_distance_phi_after_sliding() + (ball.get_distance_x() - ball.get_distance_x_after_sliding()) / ball.get_radius())
                        current_values = [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(),ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                        ball.list.append(current_values)
            elif ball.get_motion_status() == 'not_moving':
                current_values = [ball.get_distance_x(), ball.get_velocity_x(), ball.get_distance_y(),ball.get_velocity_y(), ball.get_distance_phi(), ball.get_velocity_phi()]
                ball.list.append(current_values)
            else:
                print('Error')

                
        

def draw(self):
    for ball in self.list:
        
        
        plt.plot(time_array, [item[1] for item in ball.list], label='Velocity_x')
        plt.show()
        plt.plot(time_array, [item[3] for item in ball.list], label='Velocity_y')
        plt.show()
        plt.plot(time_array, [item[2] for item in ball.list], label='Distance_y')
        plt.legend();
        plt.xlabel('t[s]');
        plt.ylabel('vx,vy[m/s], y[m]');
        plt.title('Ball movement');
        plt.xlim([0, np.max(b1.get_time_after_rolling())])
        
        """plt.plot(time_array,[item[4] for item in ball.list], label='Velocity_phi')
        plt.show()"""
def animate(self):
    # ANIMATION
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-1.5 + 0, 200 + 10),
                  ylim=(0, 100 + 2))
    lines=[]
    for i in range(len(self.list)):
        line, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', lw=2, color='b')
        lines.append(line)

    title = ax.text(0.5, 1.05, "Animation of ball movement", bbox={'facecolor': 'w', 'alpha': 0.5, 'pad': 5},
                    transform=ax.transAxes, ha="center")

    time_template = 'time = %.1fs'
    time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        time_text.set_text('')
        return line, time_text

    def animate(frame):
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            x_out = [[item[0] for item in self.list[i].list][frame],[item[0] for item in self.list[i].list][frame] + np.sin([item[4] for item in self.list[i].list][frame]) * radius]
            y_out = [[item[2] for item in self.list[i].list][frame],[item[2] for item in self.list[i].list][frame] + np.cos([item[4] for item in self.list[i].list][frame]) * radius]
            lines[i].set_data((x_out, y_out))

        time_text.set_text(time_template % (frame * a / b))
        return lines

    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=b, interval=a / b * 1000)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, ID, distance_x, velocity_x, distance_y, velocity_y, distance_phi, velocity_phi, radius, mass,list):
        self.ID = ID
        self.distance_x = distance_x
        self.velocity_x = velocity_x
        self.distance_y = distance_y
        self.velocity_y = velocity_y
        self.distance_phi = distance_phi
        self.velocity_phi = velocity_phi
        self.radius = radius
        self.mass = mass
        self.list=list

    def get_ID(self):
        return self.ID

    def get_distance_x(self):
        return self.distance_x

    def get_velocity_x(self):
        return self.velocity_x

    def get_distance_y(self):
        return self.distance_y

    def get_velocity_y(self):
        return self.velocity_y

    def get_distance_phi(self):
        return self.distance_phi

    def get_velocity_phi(self):
        return self.velocity_phi

    def get_radius(self):
        return self.radius

    def get_mass(self):
        return self.mass

    def set_distance_x(self, distance_x):
        self.distance_x = distance_x

    def set_velocity_x(self, velocity_x):
        self.velocity_x = velocity_x

    def set_distance_y(self, distance_y):
        self.distance_y = distance_y

    def set_velocity_y(self, velocity_y):
        self.velocity_y = velocity_y

    def set_distance_phi(self, distance_phi):
        self.distance_phi = distance_phi

    def set_velocity_phi(self, velocity_phi):
        self.velocity_phi = velocity_phi

    def set_radius(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def set_mass(self, mass):
        self.mass = mass

    def get_motion_status(self):
        """
        Function used to determine motion state of the ball.
        """
        if self.velocity_x == 0 and self.distance_y == self.radius:
            state = "not_moving"
        elif self.distance_y > self.radius or self.velocity_y > 0:
            state = "projectile_motion"
        elif self.distance_y < self.radius and abs(self.velocity_y) > 0:
            state = "collision"
        elif self.velocity_y == 0 and self.distance_y == self.radius and abs(self.velocity_x) - abs(
            self.velocity_phi) * self.radius > 0.001:
            state = "sliding"
        elif self.velocity_y == 0 and self.distance_y == self.radius and abs(self.velocity_x) - abs(
            self.velocity_phi) * self.radius < 0.001 and abs(self.velocity_x) > 0:
            state = "rolling"
        else:
            print('Error at determinating motion state!')

        return state

    """Used for  calculating distances after collision"""

    def set_time_after_collision(self, time_after_collision):
        self.time_after_collision = time_after_collision

    def get_time_after_collision(self):
        return self.time_after_collision

    def set_time_after_sliding(self, time_after_sliding):
        self.time_after_sliding = time_after_sliding

    def get_time_after_sliding(self):
        return self.time_after_sliding

    def set_time_after_rolling(self, time_after_rolling):
        self.time_after_rolling = time_after_rolling

    def get_time_after_rolling(self):
        return self.time_after_rolling

    def set_distance_phi_after_sliding(self, distance_phi_after_sliding):
        self.distance_phi_after_sliding = distance_phi_after_sliding

    def get_distance_phi_after_sliding(self):
        return self.distance_phi_after_sliding

    def set_distance_x_after_sliding(self, distance_x_after_sliding):
        self.distance_x_after_sliding = distance_x_after_sliding

    def get_distance_x_after_sliding(self):
        return self.distance_x_after_sliding

    def set_distance_phi_after_rolling(self, distance_phi_after_rolling):
        self.distance_phi_after_rolling = distance_phi_after_rolling

    def get_distance_phi_after_rolling(self):
        return self.distance_phi_after_rolling

    def set_velocity_x_after_sliding(self, velocity_x_after_sliding):
        self.velocity_x_after_sliding = velocity_x_after_sliding

    def get_velocity_x_after_sliding(self):
        return self.velocity_x_after_sliding
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tic=time.time()
    H = 1.5
    m = 0.5
    v_0 = 10
    g = 9.81
    alpha_0 = 30 * np.pi / 180
    x0 = 0
    phi0 = 0
    v_phi0 = 0
    radius = 0.10
    epsilon = 0.2
    mi = 0.3
    f = 0.2
    theta = f / radius
    a = 5
    b = 1000
    time_array = np.linspace(0, a, b)

    #INITIALIZATION
    b1 = Ball(1, 0, v_0 * np.cos(alpha_0), H, v_0 * np.sin(alpha_0), 0, 0, radius, 1,[])
    b2 = Ball(2, 0, v_0 * np.cos(alpha_0), 2*H, v_0 * np.sin(alpha_0), 0, 0, radius, 1,[])

    Zogemaroge = Balls([b1,b2],time_array)#####ADDING BALLS TO NEW CLASS
    Zogemaroge.time_solution()#####FILING TABLE OF ALL BALLS WITH 6 VARIABLES
    Zogemaroge.draw()#####GAPHS DISPLAY

    Zogemaroge.animate()#####ANIMATION DISPLAY
    tok=time.time()
    computing_time=tok-tic
    print(f'Computing time = {computing_time: .2f}s.')
```

Comment: Are you getting any issues in Spyder? This would most commonly be caused by the code running in different environments. For future questions, it would be good to have a much shorter example.

Comment: Are you getting errors? + There seems to be something wrong with your indents in the code you attached.

Comment: Yeah I don't know how to copy and paste whole code here, I had to manually add 4 spaces each row and it seems that I've missed a couple of rows. But regarding issues while using Spyder, I got the animation to work on a previous problem, so I don't see why it wouldn't work now. As I said, this code works fine in PyCharm.

Comment: In Spyder, please go to the menu `Tools > Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics`, go to the option called `Backend`, change it to `Automatic`, apply the changes and restart Spyder. That should make your animation work.